# Android and box shadow property

Tags: android, css, box-shadow

I have the following code to make a box shadow:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 20vw 0 #000;
```

It will not work on Android.  I am running 4.4.2 and Chrome 45.

Comment: I changed the units from ````vw```` to a pixel until and it worked great.

Comment: don't forget browser prefixes i.e: -webkit, -moz, -o etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code *should* work. It's likely that 20vw (which is 20% of the width of the browser window) is far too high and the inset shadow takes up the entire element.